# Cannot resolve class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: java, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to make an android app with a toolbar, but I get the above error message. What is the problem? I created my program sofar with whatching youtube videos (I am a beginner), but now I'm stuck:the dependencies of my build.gradle file are different from one in the youtube video. I for instance dont have the following implementation:`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'`
Everything would be fine if I had this line, if I could copy and paste it in the next line change it with `implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'`
This is the code in my activity_main.xml file, the error occurs here:

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />`
```

And this are the dependencies of my build.gradle file:

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

}

What can I do?
I hope you got everything to answer my question.

Comment: *textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + text + "\r\n");*

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, don't use setText(...). This will cause the Document to delete all the  existing Elements of the Document and it will then need to reparse the text to rebuild the Elements of the Document. A lot of unnecessary work when you can either use the `append(.,..)` method, or `Document.insertString(...)` methods. Also a Document only stores "\n" as the newline string.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that text that gets displayed the first time gets "deleted" because the other text is now displayed instead of the first text.

Don't use the `setText(...)` method. This will remove the existing text before adding the new text.

Instead use the `append(...)` method. Something like:

```
textArea.append("\nAnother line of text.");
```

to append the text to the end of the Document.

Or you can use the `Document.insertString(...)` method to insert new text anywhere in the Document of the text area.